# Import a Excel File in Jubula. Data types and updating

Tags: excel, jubula

The problem is that the parameters entered in `Excel` are read as string in `Jubula`. But I also need them as `integer` or `boolean`.

Is there a way to predefine the data type in `Excel`?

And can I update them without reimporting?
Anyone have a clue about his ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to Excel sheets you could use Central Datasets.

It can be edited in Jubula and you can specify the type of it's columns.